# Url rewrite with parameter using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a URL `page.php?id=param` which is creating dynamically.

In this URL `page.php` and `param` are dynamic so my HTML link looks like

```
<a href="page.php?id=param">link</a>
```

I need this URL as

```
mydomain.com/param
```

and it should go to `page.php` and the parameter `id` should be used from `page.php`.

This is the code I'm using right now

```
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php?id=123 to /dir/foo/123
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?id=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo/12 to /dir/foo.php?id=12

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?([^/.]+)?/?([^/.]+)?/?([^/.]+)?$ /$1.php?id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

But the rewrite is as follows:

```
mydomain.com/page/param
```

The required output should be:

```
mydomain.com/param
```

Comment: Show us your .htaccess file so far, what have you tried?

Comment: @Adam   ,  Hi I have edited the question please check the code .
  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^page/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    page.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

L (last - stop processing rules)
NC (case insensitive)

Also view this tutorial [URL Rewriting for Beginners](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)